# Localization of input parameters names at JasperReports Server

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have a report wherein I am trying localization. I have the resource bundles ready. The localization is working for column headers. But not working for the parameter names at *JasperReports Server*. The jrxml and .properties is as follows. Any ideas on why the parameters names  do not reflect in the locale selected would be of great help. I am logging in with pt-BR locale

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="testinterntionalization" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" resourceBundle="testinterntionalization" uuid="c3bdcfb8-c39a-4ce6-b38c-e7f05aa12d1b">
    <property name="ireport.jasperserver.url" value="http://54.169.66.240/jasperserver-pro/"/>
    <property name="ireport.jasperserver.report.resource" value="/organizations/organization_1/Clients/DEV/testinterntionalization_files/main_jrxml"/>
    <property name="ireport.jasperserver.reportUnit" value="/organizations/organization_1/Clients/DEV/testinterntionalization"/>
    <!-- some styles here -->
    <subDataset name="Dataset1" uuid="1d6f72b2-0f11-41ac-b81e-e83ff3318002">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="mysqldev"/>
        <parameter name="Name" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <parameter name="Country" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <parameter name="State" class="java.lang.String">
            <parameterDescription><![CDATA[]]></parameterDescription>
        </parameter>
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[select * from testinternationalization;]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="country" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="state" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="name" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="age" class="java.lang.Integer">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <parameter name="Name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="Country" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="State" class="java.lang.String">
        <parameterDescription><![CDATA[]]></parameterDescription>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select * from testinternationalization]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="country" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="state" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="age" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <summary>
        <band height="200" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="100" width="510" height="100" uuid="808bf878-b921-4858-b9d4-4dee5c866c89"/>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="Dataset1" uuid="169432ea-4c71-4fae-ab33-f344d48e7612">
                        <datasetParameter name="Country">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{country}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <datasetParameter name="State">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{state}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <datasetParameter name="Name">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                        <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="100" uuid="6a314d61-4759-4396-9796-bc890f4018d0">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="700b5c4a-53ee-4c25-9202-a7cf5960b8f1">
                                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                                </reportElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{country}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="100" uuid="96d38f9c-1461-4cf6-b43d-5ddc7b031a19">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="07dbe77e-5f72-44b8-981c-62f4dd5a7fcd">
                                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                                </reportElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{state}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="100" uuid="c26b379e-d8aa-4ede-a79c-b4e521f2bd00">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="7d71e238-237a-4ff3-83f4-8768995cab50">
                                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                                </reportElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="100" uuid="4581f4df-2aa4-474f-925c-c2d7e4cb7795">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                        <jr:detailCell style="Table_TD" height="30">
                            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="50be640f-e779-4ba7-95c7-a92377628278">
                                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                                </reportElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{age}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="70" width="100" height="30" uuid="73e572e7-39ab-4366-a8b9-2ef5ecfbcc6d"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$R{country}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="100" y="70" width="100" height="30" uuid="0b662ca2-f379-458f-bf5c-e9d3cba4766c"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$R{state}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="200" y="70" width="100" height="30" uuid="65697c5f-c12c-4151-98a3-ff9059e98a84"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$R{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="300" y="70" width="100" height="30" uuid="a043231c-db12-4c08-a8bd-5e058c0acb36"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$R{age}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

The properties file - testinterntionalization_pt_BR.properties

```
# portugese
country:paÃ­s
state:Estado
name:nome
age:era
net.sf.jasperreports.prompt.label.Country=paÃ­s
net.sf.jasperreports.prompt.label.State=Estado
net.sf.jasperreports.prompt.label.Name=nome
```

Comment: I have the paramters Name, Country and State. In the .properties file I have net.sf.jasperreports.prompt.label.Country=paÃ­s,
, net.sf.jasperreports.prompt.label.State=Estado
, net.sf.jasperreports.prompt.label.Name=nome. But when I login with locale pt-BR , I do not get the parameter label names in portugese

Comment: What does it mean? What kind of parameters? What is your expectation of this parameters? How did you use them?

Comment: The parameters are used to filter the data in the report. These are input parameters. The names of these parameters must change according to the locale just like how the column header names change as per locale

Comment: `These are input parameters.` - Are you using JR Server?

Comment: Yes I am using the JR server

Comment: Hi, Any ideas on this issue here? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to my problem here.

All I had to do was make the prompt names for the input controls to use $R{}.

In my case change the parameter Country to $R{Country}, parameter State to $R{State}, and parameter Name to $R{Name} and this worked !!

Thanks
Rathi